# Filtering out change of airport flights in Google Flights

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, planning

Is there an easy way to filter out flights that require a change of airport when searching using Google Flights?

Comment: You mean searching only for direct / non-stop flights?

Comment: No, I mean if I have to stop over in New York, I don't want to see flights going into one of New York's airports (eg. LGA) and leaving a "connecting" flight from a different New York airport (eg. JFK).

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want but.. did you try to click on the "more" filter (after selecting departure and arrival airports) and from there choosing the "Connecting Airports" you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

The only chance that you have is to plan the different legs of the trip in segments or plan a "Multi-city" trip where you chose the airport in question yourself.

In the drop-downs to find a city you can chose for example "New York (all airports)" instead of "New York JFK", and you can check "Airports near NY" from a list.